# Can I setup project interpreter from .tox folder

Tags: python, pycharm, tox

The 'tox' interpreter is in the '.tox' folder, after executing command `tox`. 
Are there any ways to set that interpreter to the PyCharm?

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE**: today this is made very easy with the [PyVenvManage Plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/10085-pyvenv-manage) which provides a context menu entry to directly activate any virtualenv in `.tox`.

---

Yes that's possible. You open up Settings -> Project Interpreter -> Add local and choose the python binary you want to use. It does not matter if it lives in a `.tox` folder or somewhere else.

[image]

[image]

Also see [pycharm help](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-python-interpreter.html).